# Как создать клиент серверное приложение используя javascript и java?

Tags: javascript, java, css3, html5

Есть задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос в том как лучше реализовывать это через js и java, можете ли дать ссылки на понятные материалы для чайников или какие то похожие примеры.

Я пробовал сделать все с помощью сервлетов на TomCat, но также хочу понять как это можно сделать без использования сервлетов.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[1](ftp://lab.dnict.vn/1.DNICT/2.Ebooks/Murach's/Murach%92s%20%20Java%20Servlets%20and%20JSP.pdf) - описаны основы веб-приложений на джаве. Примеры работы как клиента, так и сервера. (Английский язык, весьма простой)

[2](https://careers.epam.by/content/dam/epam/by/book_epam_by/Java.Programming.pdf) - Описаны методы взаимодействия сервера и клиента. Работа с данными на сервере. (Русский язык)

[3](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/328-sozdanie-prostogo-veb-prilozhenija-na-servletakh-i-jsp-chastjh-1) - пример создания простого веб-приложения. (Русский язык)